# setup azure server for outside access

Tags: azure, server, remote-access

How do you deploy a website in Windows Azure so that it can have outside access? I'm not that familiar with it and I have no idea where to start.

All the info I have is that I have a cloudapp.net website. I can access my remote desktop through .cloudapp.net. And I have an IIS Manager.

This all sounds stupid, but I need to start somewhere. And I need help. Thanks.

EDIT: More info. From my extensive search, I found that endpoints might do the trick. I want the website to be accessed through a port (sample.cloudapp.net:1010). I did some tinkering on it but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a cloudapp.net website, it means that you have a cloud service for your website. You could take a simpler approach and set up a Web App instead, which would give you an azurewebsites.net domain. **Either way, the full domain name will be a public URL for your website available at port 80.**

If you prefer to stick with a cloud service, check out the official documentation:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/

If you opt for a simpler Web App (my recommendation for beginners), the following URL contains links to documentation and a short video to get started with Web Apps:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/

Web Apps can be deployed in multiple ways, including Visual Studio, FTP or Continous Integration directly from source control. If you need help with deploying the web app, I have a step by step guide and video tutorial:

- http://wakeupandcode.com/deploy-your-web-site-web-app-on-azure/

Hope that helps! :)